# Games are/aren't included in different version/installations of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation

So, I have two different computers running Windows 7... one is a laptop running the 7 Ultimate RC 32-bit and the other is a desktop running Professional 64-bit. The laptop has the usual games that come with 7, and the first installation of the 7 Professional 64-bit on the desktop had the games as well. But after reformatting my hard drive and doing a second clean install of 7 Professional 64-bit on my desktop, there were no games whatsoever.

What could be the cause of the inconsistency and where would I be able to get these games without doing another clean install? (My mom loves Freecell. =P)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the games aren't installed in clean installs. They are usually enabled when manf send out their laptop, along with their drivers, bloatware, etc.

Start > Control Panel 
Search "Games"
Click "Turn Windows Features on or off"
"Games" are at the top. You can select all of them or individual ones.

Comment: Thanks alot! I see alot of other features in here that I can enable/disable too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea about the cause, but you should be able to install your games through the Control Panel => Programs and Features => There click "Turn Windows features on or off":

[image]